# Cannot extract href from a tags within span elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the href links (shown below) after extracting the span tags. However, it is throwing the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/qeq981/Desktop/work.py", line 34, in 
    print(element.find('a')['href'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I am using the following code:
`result2 = soup.find_all('span', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap'})
for element in result2:
    print(element)
    print(element.find('a')['href'])`

However, if I omit the `['href']`, I get all the span tags:

`<span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="https://www.mobygames.com/game/linux/americas-army-operations">Linux</a> (<em>2003</em>)</span>
<a href="https://www.mobygames.com/game/linux/americas-army-operations">Linux</a>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="https://www.mobygames.com/game/macintosh/americas-army-operations">Macintosh</a> (<em>2003</em>)</span>
<a href="https://www.mobygames.com/game/macintosh/americas-army-operations">Macintosh</a>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/americas-army-operations">Windows</a> (<em>2002</em>)</span>
<a href="https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/americas-army-operations">Windows</a>`

How can I extract the href?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with python syntax, but would it be element.find('a[href]') ?

Comment: No. I'm pretty sure it's ('a')['href'] because it works when I use the same code to extract the hrefs from div tags

Comment: The accepted answer says there is no error in/issue with your code, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the HTML code you posted the script works, fine (so the error has to be elsewhere in your HTML code).

To be *extra sure* that you extract the correct tags, you can use CSS selector `span[style="white-space: nowrap"] a[href]` to select only `<a>` tags with "href=" under specified `<span>` tags.

For example (`txt` is snippet from your question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('span[style="white-space: nowrap"] a[href]'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.mobygames.com/game/linux/americas-army-operations
https://www.mobygames.com/game/macintosh/americas-army-operations
https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/americas-army-operations
```

Comment: @usr2564301 There could be `<span>` tag without the `<a>` inside. Therefore the `TypeError` exception.

Comment: But not in the question as posed.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, apparently OP has posted HTML snippet that works with his code. I edited my answer.